# Power BI-Communication between Power BI embedded and host page

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Right now we are trying to implement Power BI embedded as a solution. I am wondering if there is a way to send a token, parameter, variable, etc. from Power BI to our host page. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This needs more context. You've already embedded a Power BI report/dashboard, and you want to send some piece of information from the report back to your web application?

Comment: @extensionhelp exactly, how can I send back some data to my web application?

Comment: If you just want values of slicers that user has selected, I think that can be done with the JavaScript API. If you're looking for more data than that, I'd look at PowerApps.